# Does absence of serialization errors mean absence of pitfalls?

Tags: java, serialization

Thinking about what is serializable and what is not, do I get it right that if no error messages pop up during de/serialization then everything has been perfectly serialized and deserialized? Or is it still possible while not getting any errors to have my object somehow damaged or changed during de/serialization?

My question may seem odd but it's rather difficult for a newbie like myself to keep track of every part of an object (which is fairly vast) whether this part can be serialized or not. So I'd rather fully rely on error indications if it's an adequate approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually not. Absence of error in writing/reading serializable object to/from DataStream means there is no exceptional situations. But that **doesn't** mean that you will get consistent data.

You could read a lot more in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) by Bloch. There are several chapters concerning serialization.